# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cqlTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to create a standalone application using spring-data-cassandra(1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT).
When attempted to create the application context 
using 'new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml")' the below exception is thrown
(My context.xml is [here](http://apaste.info/neM))

Appreciate any hints on where I am doing wrong.

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cqlTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cqlTemplate' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
 at com.nosql.MainApp.search(MainApp.java:20)
 at com.nosql.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cqlTemplate' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
 ... 16 more
2014-11-03 15:50:07,147 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#2e5d4162': [cassandraCluster]
```

P.S:- never used spring before.

Answer (score 1):

I used configuration from [there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/cassandra.adoc) (example 7):

```
<!-- Loads the properties into the Spring Context and uses them to fill
in placeholders in the bean definitions -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:cassandra.properties" />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Cassandra Cluster -->
<cassandra:cluster contact-points="${cassandra.contactpoints}"
port="${cassandra.port}" />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Cassandra Session, built from the Cluster, and attaching
to a keyspace -->
<cassandra:session keyspace-name="${cassandra.keyspace}" />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Default Cassandra Mapping Context used by CassandraConverter -->
<cassandra:mapping>
  <cassandra:user-type-resolver keyspace-name="${cassandra.keyspace}" />
</cassandra:mapping>

<!-- REQUIRED: The Default Cassandra Converter used by CassandraTemplate -->
<cassandra:converter />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Cassandra Template is the building block of all Spring
Data Cassandra -->
<cassandra:template id="cassandraTemplate" />

<!-- OPTIONAL: If you are using Spring Data for Apache Cassandra Repositories, add
your base packages to scan here -->
<cassandra:repositories base-package="org.spring.cassandra.example.repo" />
```

and got the same error till i enabled cassandra repositories via annotation `@EnableCassandraRepositories` in main application class. It's something like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:app-integration.xml")
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, Spring is not able to find cqlTemplate named bean. 
    you have to create the same in you spring context.
    You can follow below link for XML Configuration (section 4.3.2).
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/cassandra.core.html.

Comment: Is this issue resolved, I am facing similar issue in my stand alone application where on application startup it fails with the same error. I am trying to use Spring Data with Cassandra Repository.

Comment: yes, created cqlTemplate bean as specified here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/cassandra.core.html#cassandra-connectors.xmlconfig